# How to run a list of programs one-by-one in shell script?

Tags: shell

How to run a list of programs one-by-one in shell script?

This list of programs looks like:

```
#! /bin/ksh
export UP=user/pass
./abc $UP
./mno $UP
./uvx $UP
```

To execute this list the shell script scheduler.ksh looks like:

```
#! /bin/ksh
val=`tail -n +3 list.ksh`
echo $val
for i in $val
do
echo `$i`
done
```

I tested for one program and the output is:

```
./abc $UP

./scheduler.ksh[6]: $UP: not found [No such file or directory]
```

What should I do?
Thank you for your answers

Comment: Huh? Your first script executes all your programs one after the other already. What's this `scheduler` script supposed to add to the mix?

Comment: The problem seems to be in your scripts that uses `scheduler.ksh`. Check how the variable `$UP` used in your scripts and how it is passed along.

Answer (score 0):

The name for first korn shell script is list.ksh

The second one it is scheduler.ksh

In fact I want a list with the name of programs (list.ksh) to be run in second program (scheduler.ksh).

So far what I tested and it seems ok, the first file has just the names of programs and no $UP (user/pass), the second program is reading the first file and skip the first line.

```
   #! /bin/ksh
    val=`list.ksh tail -n +2`
    echo $val
    for i in $val
    do
    echo `./$i user/pass`
    done
```

Comment: Is this a further explanation of the original question? If so, you should click `edit` under your original question and update that and delete this *"answer"*. If this is, in fact, the answer you were seeking, you must know it is correct, in which case you should *accept* it as correct by clicking the hollow tick/check-mark beside the vote count.

Comment: I will love to receive another opinion to first version of files for not having hard code in second file for user and password. Also I have programs for which I have to pass a parameter and will be difficult to manage all these in scheduler.ksh. For example list.ksh could have a program like:  abc user/pass E or another example: bcd user/pass input_file